# Was my latest Air Berlin flight in violation of some in-flight procedures?

Tags: airliner, cabin-pressure

I was quite surprised about one (all?) of doors on my latest Air Berlin flight. In particular:

- the "Door locking indicator" was *empty* (black),
- the "Cabin pressurized" light was *not lighten* and
- the "Remove before flight" red strip was *not removed*.

[image: red strip reading “REMOVE BEFORE FLIGHT”]

<sub>(I am the owner of this picture and I authorize anyone to use it for any purpose except illegal activity.)</sub>

The plane landed safely and there was no noticeable in-flight change of air flow/pressure etc. Still, I wonder if the described situation is a violation of some in-flight procedures or at least odd in any way?

Comment: I would have asked a cabin attendant about it!

Comment: How long a flight was this? In other words, was it just an up and right down flight to get between two relatively close airports?

Comment: The door may have been inoperative, hence all of those things.  So long as the crew is aware of the situation, no violations would have occurred.

Comment: @mins: Sorry, I don't have. But, if I'm not mistaken then lever was as close to pin and red strip itself as possible.

Comment: @Terry. Nope. It was 6,5 hours long TXL->AUH flight. Picture was captured around the middle of this flight.

Comment: @Moo: If by "inoperative" you mean that these doors weren't use for boarding and leaving the plane then you're correct. These were close to the left wing doors.

Comment: @trejder I mean the door may have been marked on the maintenance list as "not to be used" - maybe a defective slide etc.  How full was the flight?

Comment: @Moo: I'm unable to access such information. Defective or not, shouldn't this pin be removed and "cabin pressurized" light turned on? This was an A330 flight nearly entirely full. In my (tail) section (where these doors were) I managed to see 2-3 empty chairs.

Comment: I did a Google search using "How many aircraft emergency exits can be inoperative?" and it appears that it's legal to dispatch some aircraft with one inoperative. For example, http://fsims.faa.gov/wdocs/policy%20letters/pl-001_r03_d00.htm. It appears that some restrictions may be required.

Comment: @Terry Assuming that doors being inoperative is the real cause and explanation for things observed by me -- this could be a good answer to my question. I'm still confused, however", why "cabin pressurized" light was not on. I assumed that it should be on whether cabin is pressurized (mine obviously was) irrespective of doors being inoperative or not.

Comment: @trejder are you talking about the "cabin pressurised" light on the door?  That may simply be part of the reason the door is inoperative...  As for removing the pin, not really as that is an indicator that the door is inoperative and will restrict the use of the door.

Comment: @Moo. OK, thanks. I think, that you / Terry / someone may gather together all the comments and formulate some kind of summary answer here.

Comment: I can't tell from this picture where the pin (and attached "remove before flight" strip) was actually placed. The thing does need to be kept somewhere during flight; it's not removed from the aircraft entirely.

Comment: @ZachLipton Yes. But, it shouldn't be kept inside the door, right?

Comment: It is usually attached to a different part of the door it belongs to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The safety pin is in its *stowage* position - ie. where it is supposed to be stored when **not** in use, as you can see in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NA5B1OhEbg). The red streamer is usually tucked away out of sight, but some airlines seem to leave it visible. Also, it appears from your photo that the arming handle is over to the right, ie. in the 'armed' position, as it should be in flight.

The Door Locking Indication is green-lettering-on-black for LOCKED, as you can see at 0:28 in [this video](https://youtu.be/LS_KiEH84BM?t=28s), or red-lettering-on-black for UNLOCKED. But that lettering may not be very evident unless you are quite close to the door and looking almost directly at the indicator.

As far as I am aware, the Cabin Pressurized light is not normally illuminated in flight - it flashes red if-and-only-if the door handle is moved towards the OPEN position AND the cabin is pressurized, as you can see at 1:04 in [this video](https://youtu.be/K6fNrvbAnFM?t=1m4s).

Comment: You have managed to explain almost anything, thank you. As for the second part -- since I was staying in a quite long toilet queue I had pretty much enough time to actually stare directly into the "Door Locking Indicator" and I'm 100% positive that there was absolutely nothing inside, neither red nor green and no text. It was just a black, empty strip. Since we managed to figure out that these doors were inoperative, this may be a repercussion of that fact.